# Emacs Lisp: Byte-compiler warning for undefined functions in apply, mapcar

Tags: elisp, runtime-error, compiler-warnings, higher-order-functions, top-down

When you perform a function call `(myfunction ...`) in emacs lisp, the byte compiler will warn if the function isn't known to be defined at compile time. This helps greatly with a top-down programming style, since then I can happily write

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon (lambda (a b) (equal (upcase a) (upcase b)))
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))
```

When I compile the byte compiler tells me that I haven't yet defined or misspelled the two `foo-` functions.

However, if the lambda expression becomes complex some more restructuring makes sense, e.g.

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon 'foo-equal
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))
```

Now there is a problem though... `'foo-equal` is now a symbol and only at runtime when executing `foo-filter-by-function` a check whether `'foo-equal` is defined will be executed. Something that normally is a compile-time warning suddenly has become runtime-error. The same problem applies for builtin higher-order functions such as `mapcar`, `apply`...

Is there some possibility to make the byte compiler recognize, that e.g. the first argument to `mapcar` should be a function and thus, when the argument is given as a symbol, check whether that symbol has a valid function definition, like it does with explicit `(foo-equal ..)` calls?

Note: The purpose is to allow making production code more readable, so solutions that require a change of each call to `foo-filter-by-function` or hackish code in its definition are not acceptable solutions. An example of such a counter-productive solution would be

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon (lambda (a b) (foo-equal a b)) ... )
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))
```

or

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon foo-equal
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))

(defconst foo-equal (lambda (a b) ...)
```

since both result in inferior code readability at least subjectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `#'foo-equal` instead of `'foo-equal` so as to tell the compiler that you're not just talking about the `foo-equal` symbol but about the `foo-equal` function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. If I compile 

    `(defun test-id=025b35ba8670e54d1cf ()
      (add-hook 'bla-bla-hook #'some-function)
      (mapcar #'some-function '(1 2 3)))`

I still don't get a warning about `some-function' not being known.

Comment: Right, I think you'll only get a warning if you byte-compile with Emacs-24.4, earlier versions did not catch this case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're touching the static/dynamic language question.

The code

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon 'foo-equal
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))
```

is perfectly legal lisp code which stems from its flexibility.
There are legal situations when `foo-equal` need not be defined.
I think what you meant was

```
(defun foo (bar baz)
  (foo-filter-by-functon #'foo-equal
   (foo-combine-values bar baz)))
```

It's still legal lisp code. There could be situations, although less,
when `foo-equal` need not be defined.

### The main point

It's `foo-filter-by-functon` that decides whether its argument will be called or not,
so it's logical that it should check the argument before calling:
maybe something like this:

```
(defun-carefully
    `(defun foo-filter-by-function (fun lst)
       (cl-remove-if-not fun lst)))
```

Where `defun-carefully` is a macro that will define the function,
and store in some dict that it calls its first argument.
How did it know that it calls its argument? It looked up in the same dict
that `cl-remove-if-not` calls its argument.

And if all defuns are wrapped with this macro, maybe it's possible to get
to the warnings that you want.
Maybe it's possible to redefine `defun` temporarily with `macrolet`
for the duration of `eval-buffer`.

Still it's a lot of work. I hope someone else does / did it:)

Comment: This raises follow-up questions. Basically we need code, that causes the function definition to be expanded at compile-time but at runtime calls the original function, i.e. a macro `mapcar` that performs a check and then expands to a `mapcar` functioncall. When I tried such things before I couldn't find a way to prevent emacs lisp from ending up with an infinite recursion of macro expansions. But definitely, quite some work indeed... Btw, it would rather be `byte-compile-from-buffer` which I'd need to wrap in a `cl-macrolet`. Thanks for the hint though!